# How to chain an Observable with a Single in RxJava?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, flatmap, rx-kotlin, rx-kotlin2

I am new to the Rx world so please bear with me.

My code is in Kotlin but a Java code will help also.

I have 2 methods, one of them loads tasks from the database, if there are tasks, I want to send them to the server.

```
fun getListFromDb(): Single<List<TaskEntity>> {
    return taskEntityDao.getAll()
}

 fun syncTasks(localTasks: TaskSyncRequest): Observable<ApiResponse<List<TaskEntity>>> {
    return taskServices.syncTasks(localTasks)
}
```

I know I can use flatmap to chain observables, but just couldn't get it working between Single and Observables.

Comment: You're looking for the flatMapObservable operator.
Also, if this is an HTTP network call, why does it return an Observable?, it would make a clearer intention if it did return a Single instead.

Comment: `Single` represents single item, `Observable` - sequence of item. Seems like your api shoud return "single". Anyway you can easly conver observable to single, for example with `singleOrError()` method

Comment: Yes this is actually a retrofit call, and nearly all the examples which they were covering it were using observables not single, would it be better if I changed them to single ?
if so, This will kinda fix my problem right now

Comment: Recommended reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#continuations

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `flatMapObservable`
You can use this method for transform single to observable;